# How to calculate screen-Y from data-Y in a MultiBarChart of NVD3?

Tags: javascript, json, svg, d3.js, bar-chart

I am using NVD3 library to display a stacked multiBarChart. I also need to add a single horizontal line (---) on each bar to indicate where the average value is.

I considered the last set of data (series) to be the average.

```
test_data = [
    {"key":"Series 1",  "values":[{"x":0,"y":30},{"x":1,"y":15},{"x":2,"y":10}]},
    {"key":"Series 2",  "values":[{"x":0,"y":2},{"x":1,"y":7},{"x":2,"y":3}]},
    {"key":"Average","values": [{"x":0,"y":6},{"x":1,"y":4},{"x":2,"y":40}]}
];
```

I managed to select the last series, and change the height of the  to 1 to simulate a line instead of a square. I also managed to control the location of line vertically by change the value of 'y':

```
var lastBars = $('.nv-group:last rect');
lastBars.attr('height', 2);
lastBars.attr('y',function(a, y, c){
    return parseFloat(y) + 50;
});
```

In order to place the 'horizontal line' at the right Y on screen, I need to find out how to scale the 'y' provided with the data to the corresponding 'Y' at screen to align with the correct value in Y axis.

I was reading the source code of NVD3, and it seems it is using yDomain and yScale to calculate the screen-Y value, but I am not sure how to use them and how to access them from outside the library code.

Any idea?